# The page direct effect on mobile website with jquerymobile

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

While browsing the [jquerymobile](http://jquerymobile.com/resources/) website, I see some example like [disneyworld](http://m.disneyworld.disney.go.com/) using jquerymobile technology. When I click a link to another page, the browser have not refreshed, but a loading indicator displayed on middle, then direct to the destination.

Is this effect belong to `AJAX`? and how to implement this effect?
An example for this would be appreciated, thanks.

[image]

Comment: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/methods.html $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg is what you're looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is ajax, and jQuery mobile has this setting set as default. If you wanted to do it on your website without jQuery, you would need to use GET calls to your back end actions and return the whole Page which will replace the div with ID you are posting from. If you wanted exact code for your language of choice you'd need to tell us what that is.